# Ansible: How to replace value of keys in a file?

Tags: ansible

I Have a file `/tmp/srv_info.txt` as below:

```
INVENTORY_HOSTNAME: hostname
BIOS_VERSION: biosversion
TOTAL_MEMORY: memory
VDA_SIZE: vdasize
VDB_SIZE: vdbsize
XVDA_SIZE: xvdasize
XVDC_SIZE: xvdcsize
```

I have to fill it with correct values per host, I already set the variables for each value:

```
- name: Save results
  set_fact:
    HN: "{{ ansible_hostname | default('NONE', true) }}"
    BV:  "{{ ansible_bios_version | default('NONE', true) }}"
    MEM:  "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb | default('NONE', true) }} MB"
    XVDA:  "{{ ansible_devices.xvda.size.split(',') | first | default('NONE', true) }}"
    XVDC:  "{{ ansible_devices.xvdc.size.split(',') | first | default('NONE', true) }}"
    VDA:  "{{ ansible_devices.vda.size | default('NONE', true) }}"
    VDB:  "{{ ansible_devices.vdb.size | default('NONE', true) }}"
```

How can I change `/tmp/srv_info.txt` with appropriate values, for example:

```
HOSTNAME:   host_one.lab.infra
BIOS_VERSION:  4.13
TOTAL_MEMORY: 3900 MB
VDA_SIZE: 25 GB
VDB_SIZE: 10 GB
XVDA_SIZE: NONE
XVDC_SIZE: NONE
```

I Can use module `replace`, or `lineinfile`  for each value, but then need to call 7 times the module.
I would like to loop the variable list, find the corresponding script, and replace the value in the file.
But could not achieve yet.
Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exactly how the file should look like on the target machine, use a template. That's what they are for.

Template:

```
HOSTNAME: {{HN}}
BIOS_VERSION:  {{BV}}
TOTAL_MEMORY: {{MEM}}
VDA_SIZE: {{VDA}}
VDB_SIZE: {{VDB}}
XVDA_SIZE: {{XVDA}}
XVDC_SIZE: {{XVDB}}
```

Playbook:

```
- template:
    src: src.j2
    dest: /tmp/srv_info.txt
    [owner, group, mode...]
```

Comment: Thanks @SipSeb - yes template usage was good.

Answer (score 0):

For example, use [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html)

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: |
          HOSTNAME: {{ HN }}
          BIOS_VERSION: {{ BV }}
          TOTAL_MEMORY: {{ MEM }}
          VDA_SIZE: {{ VDA }}
          VDB_SIZE: {{ VDB }}
          XVDA_SIZE: {{ XVDA }}
          XVDC_SIZE: {{ XVDC }}
        dest: /tmp/srv_info.txt
```

The next option is to put the content into a file and use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-builtin-template-template-a-file-out-to-a-target-host).

---

If you want to change only some of the values read the hashes from the file into a dictionary and use this dictionary to set the defaults. For example

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: /tmp/srv_info.txt
        name: srv_info
    - set_fact:
        HN: "{{ ansible_hostname | default(srv_info.INVENTORY_HOSTNAME) }}"
        BV:  "{{ ansible_bios_version | default(srv_info.BIOS_VERSION) }}"
        MEM:  "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb | default(srv_info.TOTAL_MEMORY) }} MB"
        XVDA:  "{{ ansible_devices.xvda.size.split(',') | first | default(srv_info.XVDA_SIZE) }}"
        XVDC:  "{{ ansible_devices.xvdc.size.split(',') | first | default(srv_info.XVDC_SIZE) }}"
        VDA:  "{{ ansible_devices.vda.size | default(srv_info.VDA_SIZE) }}"
        VDB:  "{{ ansible_devices.vdb.size | default(srv_info.VDB_SIZE) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, Got it, finally it was simple, I was mind-boggling to do it with a loop, no need. Thanks again, Tried both, all work fine!